# JWT token is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

In JWT token when I am trying to get it always says undefined.
In postman its working, but when i am sending though the client it give me an error.

```
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
const config=require('config');

module.exports=function(req,res,next){

     const token  = req.body.token || req.query.token || 
     req.headers['x-access-token']||req.header('x-auth-token');
     if(!token){
          res.status(401).send("not authorized user");
        }
     else {
        try {
        const decoded=jwt.verify(token,"my_secret");
        req.userData=decoded;
        next();
    }catch(ex){
        res.status(401).send("invalid token");
    }
   }
}
```

What i am doing wtrong. How can I get this token on client side and send it to server?